# reactions for alcohols into alkyl halides with 100% retention

Tags: organic-chemistry

I learnt that alcohols can be converted into alkyl halides in the following ways with 1/2 steps:

1. adding H-X (X=Cl/Br/I): primary alcohol: inversion (SN2), secondary / tertiary alcohol: racemization (forming Carbocation)
2. PBr3 + pyridine / SOCl2 + pyridine: primary / secondary alcohol: inversion (SN2), tertiary alcohol: no reaction as unavaliable for SN2
3. TsCl + pyridine: primary alcohol: inversion (SN2), secondary / tertiary alcohol: racemization (forming Carbocation, if I am correct on this mechanism)

Is there any way for me to make a 100% retention alkyl halide from any degrees of alcohol with 1/2 steps?

Comment: Use just $\ce{SOCl2}$, it gives an SNi mechanism. Also 100% retention is bit hard to achieve practically since there may be different sub reactions. and you also need an enantiomerically pure substrate inorder to verify whether it worked.

Comment: For 100% retention you need to do a double inversion